# Number of vectors smaller than a vector with constant sum

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set $S_N$ of vectors $\vec{n}=(n_1,\ldots,n_m)$  where the $n_i$'s are non-negative integers and $\sum_i n_i=N$. I have a summation of the kind $\sum_{n \in S_N}\sum_{\vec{0}\leq \vec{k}\leq \vec{n}}$, where $\vec{k}=(k_1,\ldots,k_m)$ is also a vector of integers and $\vec{0}=(0,\ldots,0)$.

Is it possible to say how many times a given vector $\vec{k}$ will appear? I believe that the vector $\vec{k}=\vec{0}$ will appear ${N+m-1\choose m-1}$ times, since it appears exactly once for each element of $S_N$. I am not sure if a similar expression can be given for the other possible values of $\vec k$.

Pointers to papers or known results concerning this type of summations would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector $\vec k$ with $\sum_jk_j=r\le N$, will appear $\binom{N-r+m-1}{m-1}$ times, since that's the number of ways in which you can add $m$ non-negative integers to it that sum to $N-r$.

Comment: Is it possible that this is just a bound? You can have vectors $\vec{k}$ with $r\leq N$ that do not satisfy the condition $\vec{k}\leq \vec{n}$. Take for example $\vec{n}=(1,2,3)$ and $\vec{k}=(2,0,0)$.

Comment: @MarkRosberg: Sure you can. I don't see how that invalidates my argument. Have you found a case where the binomial coefficient doesn't give the right result?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I implemented it in MATLAB and your solution is exact!

Comment: @MarkRosberg: Then may I humbly suggest that you accept the answer so that the question doesn't remain in the unanswered category?